# How to replace quotes with apostrophe in php

Tags: php

I am using below given code to replace all the quotes with apostrophe in php. But this php code is not working. Where i am wrong. Kindly guide me.

```
    <?php

text = '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 300*250 box -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>';


$textnew = str_replace('"', "'", $text);

?>
```

Comment: $ is missing., also use add_slashes

Answer (score 2):

Declared variable on PHP should start with $ sign.

```
$text
```